# (MySQl) Database Structure for Pyramid-Like Ecard System

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I want to develop an ecard system which will allow users to track how many people they reached in total. Let's say person A sends an ecard to B, C, D. B, C, D send ecards to E, F, G, H, ... It might also happen that B sends to C and C to A, B, D.

If possible I would like to track both, the number of mails triggered from person A, as well as the number of people reached. The question is, how would a database structure for that task look like?

To simplify, let's say we have a table `profile` with columns `id_profile` and `email`. Is it possible with another table called `mailing`, containing the columns `id_mailing`, `id_sender`, `id_recipe` -> is it possible to track even 2nd level recipes with this table etc?

I do not see an easy solution. Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: What have you Googled?What have you tried?

Comment: @davidstrachan: when googling pyramid database structure I stumbled upon other stuff, not related to database or php/sql. I have not started coding, but drafted different schemes for a db structure on paper, but as said without finding a clue... that's why I turned here for help/guidance.

Comment: Try Googling hierarchical databases. Tutorial                        http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/